# Find index in javascript array between to matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I have an array, lets say:

```
const section = [{type: TYPE_B}, {type: TYPE_A}, {type: TYPE_B}, {type: TYPE_A}, {type: TYPE_A}];
```

I want to get the index of the first element with TYPE_A where the next element is also TYPE_A

This is what i tried:

```
const firstMatch = section.reduce((a, b) => {
   if (a.type === TYPE_A && b.type === TYPE_A) {
     return a;
   }
});
```

This does not work though, since it returns undefined for all non matches and the code crashes on next iteration.

Comment: Before writing the code you tried, did you take time to learn what `reduce` actually does?

Comment: ...and why would the result be index `3`? From your description, it should be index `2`.

Comment: My guess is he wants to find the first index of two `TYPE_A` elements together.

Comment: please add why you want to get 4 or 3 or which value ever.

Comment: and what is the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want is to find the first index of two consequent `TYPE_A` elements, then you could use `findIndex` in the following way:

```
section.findIndex((e, idx, arr) => e.type === TYPE_A && arr[idx+1] && arr[idx+1].type === TYPE_A)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findIndex`

```js
const section = [{type: 'TYPE_B'}, {type: 'TYPE_A'}, {type: 'TYPE_B'}, {type: 'TYPE_A'}, {type: 'TYPE_A'}];
const toFind = 'TYPE_A';

let idx = section.findIndex((o, i, a) => a[i - 1] && a[i - 1].type === toFind && a[i + 1] && a[i + 1].type === toFind && o.type !== toFind);

console.log(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const section = [
  {type: "TYPE_B"},
  {type: "TYPE_A"},
  {type: "TYPE_B"},
  {type: "TYPE_A"},
  {type: "TYPE_A"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < section.length - 1; i++) {
  if (section[i].type == "TYPE_A" && section[i + 1].type == "TYPE_A") {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Note: I have added quotes around every occurence of `TYPE_A` and `TYPE_B`. If these are variables, please remove the quotes. I kept them here because they will return an error if the interpreter treats them as variables (they are undefined).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and check the predecessor and the actual element for the wanted `type`.

```js
var section = [{ type: 'TYPE_B' }, { type: 'TYPE_A' }, { type: 'TYPE_B' }, { type: 'TYPE_A' }, { type: 'TYPE_A' }],
    type = 'TYPE_A',
    index = section.findIndex((o, i, a) => i && a[i - 1].type === type && o.type === type);

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const section = [{
      type: 'TYPE_B'
    }, {
      type: 'TYPE_A'
    }, {
      type: 'TYPE_B'
    }, {
      type: 'TYPE_A'
    }, {
      type: 'TYPE_A'
    }];

    var first=-1,second=-1;
    
    section.forEach((typeObj,index)=>{
       if(first===-1){
         if(typeObj.type==='TYPE_A') first=index;
       }
       else if(first>=0){
         if(typeObj.type==='TYPE_A') second=index;
       }
    })
    
    if(first>=0 && second>0) console.log(first+1);
    else console.log("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of elements that are the same equal to the next element in the array.

```
var TYPE_A = {"a":"a"};
var TYPE_B = {"b":"b"};
const section = [{type: TYPE_B}, {type: TYPE_A}, {type: TYPE_B}, {type: TYPE_A}, {type: TYPE_A}];

var results = [];
if (section.length > 1) {
    for(var i = 0; i < section.length -1;i++){
    if(section[i].type == section[i+1].type){
      results.push(i);
    }
  }
}
console.log(results);
```